# Elegant way to locate all large files (files over 200 or so megs) on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, filesystems

Basically, I'm running out of hardrive space and I've looked at the usual culprits -- downloads, media, large programs etc.

There seems to be hidden files or maybe log files that could be taking up a lot of space and I don't know how to locate them.

Comment: Run any of the tools as administrator.

Comment: Not an answer to what you asked, but may be relevant to your underlying problem: If you're not having any sort of ongoing disk problems, go look at C:\Windows\Logs\CBS - you can probably delete anything named CBSPersist*. I freed up over 100GB of a 200GB drive just doing this.